# Extracting unique messageID from sql in gridview asp.net c#

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, gridview

I have a message database that stores the private messages from users to users. I have a column called MessageID, which is a unique number. In my application, I have a message inbox (using gridview) page that shows the user who messaged you, the subject, and the create date. Next to it I have a button you can click to view the message. I am wondering if there is some way I can extract the MessageID of the message so I can use a SELECT FROM with a WHERE query to get the body of the message.

Maybe I could store the MessageID on the .aspx page somewhere but keep it hidden?

Comment: What exactly is your question? Does it have to do with retrieving the MessageID using SQL or does it have to do with storing a value in a hidden field in a .aspx page?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. My question is how to retrieve the MessageID using SQL so when you click a row in gridview, a query can retrieve the body of the message. I thought that maybe storing the MessageID somewhere on the page but having it hidden could be a possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I got a working solution! I just added a column for the MessageID on the gridview and I turned the visibility of it to be false so the user can't see it. But this way the MessageID is there and I can use it as a query parameter